# pyspark - different behavior in python console and jupyter-notebook with regex

Tags: regex, character-encoding, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to replicate result using 're.findall'(re module) that I have in python(v2.7) console in jupyter-notebook. What I know until now is jupyter-notebook gets 'ascii' as default encoding and I'm giving 'utf8'. To 'fix' that I'm using 're.LOCALE' flag in 're.findall', what solves the "crash" but doesn't gets characters like 'ç','ã' or 'ê'. It's simply truncating the 'match'. Example:

A string like: "DVD com função karaokê mondial D-14"

Applying 're.findall' function

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# lots of import here... 
import re

words = "dvd player com função karaokê mondial D-14"
brSpecialChars = r'[\w\dÁáÁàÃãÂâÉéÈèÊêÍíÓóÔÕÚúÜüÇç]'
prepositions = r'(a|ante|apos|após|ate|até|com|contra|de|desde|em|per|para|perante|por|sem|sob|sobre|tras|trás)' 
found = re.findall(r'(' + brSpecialChars + r'+\s+' + prepositions + r'\s+' + brSpecialChars + r'+)'
print "FOUND: {}".format(str(found))
```

I got this printing in console from jupyter-notebook

> (u'player com fun', u'com', u' fun')

I got this from python console

> [('player com fun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o', 'com', ' fun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o')]

I have no idea why. Can you clarify this please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Is not the solution itself, but works for this specific case.

My previous regex:

```
found = re.findall(r'(' + brSpecialChars + r'+\s+' + prepositions + r'\s+' + brSpecialChars + r'+)',words,flags=re.LOCALE
```

Now, to *bypass* any encoding crap, I can do this:

```
found = re.findall(r'([^\s]+\s+' + prepositions + r'\s+[^\s]+',words,flags=re.LOCALE)
```

The result:

> (u'player com fun\xe7\xe3o karaok\xea', u'com', u' karaok\xea')

Of course I need treat *prepositions* regex at same way. But, the accent problem is solved with that very ugly solution!

If anyone has a better idea, please post here!

Comment: You can do encoding as iso-8859-1, but utf-8 is by default if you use Python > 3.0. That should not cause a problem to your characters. Does not make sense but, can you try executing this in jupyter and console? `import sys sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Comment: Indeed! But is not a option because of company rules. The command output is 'ascii'(Only God knows why somebody set this as default encoding!) . I know that is possible to change encoding using *setdefaultencoding* but there are some problems doing that.

Comment: Default encoding for python < 3 is as stated "**python 2.x uses ASCII as a default encoding**", so, it is clear that god did not set it :p (moreover check whether both of the python versions are in sync).

Comment: Yes I know that! I don't know why! For me utf-8 is obvious as a default choice. But who am I to question this?